# Fleiss' Kappa v. Cohen's Kappa v. Cronbach's Alpha

Tags: agreement-statistics, cohens-kappa, cronbachs-alpha

I am working on a project that compares two methods of assessing whether certain topics come up in a therapy session. I am comparing a checklist full of dichotomous (y/n) items completed by an observer who listens to the therapy session to the same checklist that the therapist completes after the therapy session. There are 5 observers who are randomly assigned therapy sessions to observe. **My goal is to see the agreement between the two ways of completing the checklist.**

I've thought of a few ways to do this:

**Cohen's Kappa**

- Meets all assumptions except: the same two raters are not used for all observations.

**Fleiss' Kappa**

- Meets all assumptions except: the targets that are being rated are not technically picked out randomly from a population. The therapists in the study choose to be in the study and were not randomly selected. But, the raters were randomly assigned to observe different sessions.

**Cronbach's Alpha** (Specifically Kuder-Richardson Formula 20 (KR-20))

- I'm not sure if this technically answers the question I'm hoping to answer.

Can anyone advise on what to do? Or, if you know of any papers that do a similar thing, please send article titles. Thanks so much!

*P.S. (and somewhat unrelated) Why would the Fleiss' kappa be so different than Cohen's Kappa?*

Comment: For each session, there is only 1 observer, but it can be a different person as there are 5 observers, right?  Is the therapist always the same?  How many sessions are there?

Comment: Yes, there each session is only observed once by one of the five raters. There are over 40 therapist/patient pairs with around 100 sessions total.

Comment: So there are 100 therapists?  The therapist is different each time?

Comment: Sorry, I was still editing while I posted - I meant there are 100 sessions total, and 40 therapists. Some therapists appear more than once as we follow them and their patient through apx 10 sessions. We just don't have observer data on all sessions.

Comment: And, some therapists have multiple patients, so they a certain therapist can pop up in the data more than 10 times.

Comment: It seems implausible to me that the only thing that matters is observer vs therapist.  There are likely to be individual differences amongst the people.  That implies you want a mixed model to extract random effects and compute ICCs, but you also probably don't have enough data to support that.  So a Bayesian model might be necessary.  To have everything 'correct' is going to be pretty complicated, I think.  If you just want to say at the start of your analyses that the agreement seems OK & move forward, you might ignore the individual raters & make a descriptive statement about agreement.

Comment: Thank you! My main goal is to see if a therapist reports the same topics they mentioned in a therapy session as an outside observer listening to the same recorded therapy session. So, there are 100 sessions that have 2 sets of reports each: 1) a checklist from the therapist and 2) a checklist from an outside observer. So, I my guess is that there shouldn't be many differences between a therapist's report and the observer who listened to the same therapy session. That being said, should I try to run a bayesian model, or would some sort of Kappa work?

Comment: Unless you're very comfortable with Bayesian mixed models (which I assume you aren't, or you wouldn't be asking this), I wouldn't even attempt it.  That's my point. Do something simpler, eg, a bunch of Cohen's kappas, & say the results are just descriptive.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to consider using a quasi-independence model here.

I didn't see the length of the questionnaire so I'll assume it's 30 y/n questions for this description, but that is inconsequential. If you model this as a comparison of two methods (questionnaire at end of session (M1) vs questionnaire during recorded playback (M2)) you can represent the results as counts in a 2x2x30 (M1xM2xQ) contingency table.

Assuming independence of methods, you would fit the counts with a log-linear model. However, this would likely fit poorly as we expect the raters to agree much of the time (they are listening to the same patient after all and are likely qualified to be filling out the checklist). A Quasi-Independence model adds extra terms that effectively zero out the residuals of the main diagonal of your contingency table, i.e. it fits perfectly the cells where the raters agree. This means that only the discordant results (e.g. M1 = y, M2 = n) influence the model fit. From there you can determine whether the therapist or the observer is more prone to answering "y" or "n" and if so on which question(s).

I believe the default error distribution for log-linear models in most software is the Poisson, but you can also try the Quasipoisson or Negative Binomial to add a dispersion parameter.

Note: you won't be able to assess the results of a *particular* therapist or observer with this structure, but if you have a broad enough sample of therapists and observers and they are randomly paired this should not be a major issue (relative to the limitations of your study).

Agresti's "An Introduction to Categorical Data Analysis" has a section on this topic (8.5.2 in the Second addition)

[PSU](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat504/node/144/) Has a section on QI models as well.

Comment: Welcome to this page and thank you for your contribution. Can you give a more detailed answer? maybe refer the reader to literature? Explain your reasoning behind this suggestion?

Comment: Thanks, I've expanded the reasoning and added a few sources